# How can I personalize the template of the django-oscar?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-oscar

I'm a beginner in django/oscar.
I created my virtual env and I followed the procedure for create a new django project.

Now, I want to personalize my page without to fork the repo.I want only extend oscar's template (for example change background, add a new navbar ecc).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Start with the the documentation: [how to customise templates](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/howto/how_to_customise_templates.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the my problem.You have to copy the folder myenv/lib/site_package/oscar/..etc../template and paste her in your project's root.Obviously you have to change the path in settings.py in the TEMPLATE's section.